# Variable to select array object. (variable within variable)

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I am trying to use PHP to to loop through search terms and append them onto an SQL string before a search is conducted. However the page isn't working because of this code:

```
    $sql .= "
    WHERE Title
    LIKE '%$ss[$i]%'";
```

The full context of this code can be seen here:

```
if(isset($_POST['ss'])){
    $ss = $_POST['ss'];
    $ss = explode(' ',$ss);
    $num_search_terms = count($ss);
    $sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM CRDRecord";
    $i = 0;
    while($i <= $num_search_terms){
        $ssf=
        $sql .= "
        WHERE Title
        LIKE '%$ss[$i]%'";
        $i++;
    }
    $params = array();
    $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );
    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
    if ($row_count === false){
       echo "Error in retrieving row count.";
    }
    else {
    $jsonData = '{ "num":"Number of records-'.$row_count.',<br><br> search terms being used- <br>search 1- '.$ss[0].'<br>search2- '.$ss[1].'<BR>Number of search terms detected- '.$num_search_terms.'<br>SQL STRING: '.$sql.'" }';
       echo $jsonData;
    }
}
```

I know what I'm trying to do but can't figure out how to express it. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Errors? Exceptions? No data? What exactly is wrong and what you have tried to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't have good debugging setup. I was just wondering if there was anything obviously wrong with the snippet of code at the top...

Comment: Tried "echo-debugging"? It's messy, but better than nothing. Try to echo `$sql` just after the loop.

Comment: Thanks John, this is what I got '
 SELECT * 
 FROM CRDRecord
  WHERE Title
  LIKE '%%'
  WHERE Title
  LIKE '%%'Error in retrieveing row count.'

Comment: Ok, now look at the sql string and think. I believe you'll be able to quickly find what's wrong. IF not - consider stopping what you are doing and spending some time learning SQL, because errors are quite obvious. Also, consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: What I understood from your question was, that you don't know how to concatenate strings in PHP or you don't how to use array values in a string. Both are real PHP basics. Please refer to their manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the WHERE out of the LOOP and add a default condition to handle the concatenation

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
FROM CRDRecord WHERE 1=1 ";
$i = 0;
while($i <= $num_search_terms){
    $ssf=
    $sql .= "
    AND Title LIKE '%$ss[$i]%'";
    $i++;
}
```

Doing the way results in too many WHERE statements, you are only allowed one. The WHERE 1=1 is a method to allow you to have a single condition in the WHERE clause before you start appending other conditions.

Comment: Brilliant XYZ_909 thanks so much for your help. To the other haters that shut down this question you can do one.

Comment: I should say you might need to tweek things if you want to use OR instead of AND, but the principle point was the multiple WHERE's.